# How can make the user do QUIZZ once time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Quizz with two questions and 3 checkboxes answers for each question. 
If user answers true he can click on button to get the reward. If not no button will be affiched.
The problem that,i want user enter to this quizz once time, if he answers wrong then he can not enter again .
This is my html code:

```
<form name="qcm">
<center> <H3> Reduction survey </H3> 
<h3> QUIZ</h3>
</center>
 <hr>
 <p> Questionnaire in the form of multiple choice questions.Questions may 
 have one or more correct answers. </P>
 <p style="color:brown" > <strong>Answer the questions and check the right 
 choice(s) to get the "-40%" reduction in dress</strong> </p>
 <p> Question 1: </p>
  <p> <strong>Which occasions the dresses existes in this websites are 
  used?</strong> </p>
  <ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="q11"> prom </input> </li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="q12" >wedding</input> </li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="q13">bar party</input></li>
  </ul>
   <p> Question 2: </p>
   <p><strong> What are the materials that are the dresses fabriquated ? 
   </strong> </p>
    <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox"name="q21"> Wool </input></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"name="q22">Lining </input></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="q23"> Coton  </input></li>
     </ul>
    <center>
    <input type="button" value="Correction" onclick="testqcm(this.form)">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <script src="button.js"></script> 
    </center>
    </form>
    </body>
```

And this is my javascript code if he clicks on correction button:

```
 function testqcm(form){
  var w=window.open("", "fenêtre 2","width=500, height=300" );
  var contenu = "<html><head><title>qcm</title></head><center><h1> 
   Correction dynamique of the reduction test </h1></center><body>";

   if (form.q11.checked==true && form.q12.checked==true && 
   form.q13.checked==false){


    contenu += "<ul><li>The answer of the question 1 is True.</li>";
    }

    else 
    contenu += "<li>The answer of the question 1 is<u style='color:red;'> 
    False</u>.</li>";

     contenu += "<br>";
     if (form.q22.checked==true && form.q21.checked==false && 
     form.q23.checked==false )
    {

    contenu += "<li>The answer of the question 2 is True.</li>";
    }
    else 
    contenu += "<li>The answer of the question 2 is<u style='color:red;'> 
    False</u>.</li></ul>";

     if (form.q11.checked==true && form.q12.checked==true 
     &&form.q22.checked==true && form.q13.checked==false && 
     form.q21.checked==false && form.q23.checked==false )   {
    contenu += "<p style='color:red;'><strong> CONGRATULATIONS</strong> 
     </p> <p> You received <strong> -40% </strong> reduction in one dress 
     </p>";



   contenu += " <center><input type='button' value='Congratulations' 
   onclick=window.location.href='reduction.html'></center></body></html>";
     }
     w.document.write(contenu);

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a cookie in the users' browser when the questions are answered. When a user initializes the page look to see what question(s) they did or didn't answer, and show the appropriate state, either allowing them to finish the quiz or that they have already finished it and can't answer it again.

Comment: #thenetimp Sorry but how can i do this!

Comment: Well, that depends on your code.  Here's a tutorial on the subject  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm